# Проблема с bootstrap apache

Tags: apache, bootstrap

После загрузки сайта на сервер, слетела вся вёрстка и сайт стал выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опытным путём установил что проблема в bootstrap. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 1):

У Вас указаны пути без `/`. Например: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ru/all.css?v=5ab646713aab">`.

Самое простое - указать `<base href="/">`. Вообще, лучше проверить пути, как указывается в ответе @Qwertiy

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, путь к стилям неверный. Браузер пишет о таких ошибках в консоли.